# azure cannot create vm from vhd image

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, virtual-machine, vhd

I'm currently running into difficulty in creating an Azure VM from a custom VM image. I am following the guide from Azure from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/

I've used Waagent and deprovisioned the machine as instructed, and deallocated, generalized, and captured my machine image (I have made some modifications to the core Ubuntu 16.04LTS image available from Azure software wise).  I have successfully created the template.json file (Can provide it if needed). I then completed all the tasks below in the powershell script as outlined in the article, just extracting the parameters to variables to make things a bit easier.

```
## Global
$rgName = "testrg"
$location = "eastus"

## Storage
$storageName = "teststore"
$storageType = "Standard_GRS"

## Network
$nicname = "testnic"
$subnetName = "subnet1"
$vnetName = "testnet"
$vnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$vnetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$ipName = "TestIP"

## Compute
$vmName = "testvm"
$computerName = "testcomputer"
$vmSize = "Standard_D1_v2"
$osDiskName = $vmName + "osDisk"

#template
$fileTemplate = "C:\AzureTemplate\template.json"

azure group create $rgName -l $location

azure network vnet create $rgName $vnetName -l $location

azure network vnet subnet create --resource-group $rgName --vnet-name $vnetName --name $subnetName --address-prefix $vnetSubnetAddressPrefix

azure network public-ip create $rgName $ipName -l $location

azure network nic create $rgName $nicName -k $subnetName -m $vnetName -p $ipName -l $location

azure network nic show $rgName $nicname

azure group deployment create $rgName $computerName -f $fileTemplate
```

I am able to successfully run all the commands to create the resource group and the network components, however, when I try to run the deployment command at the bottom of the powershell script, I get the following and it just hangs here indefinitely.  Am I using the right approach to create a VM from a custom image? Or is that Azure guide outdated?

```
azure group deployment create $rgName $computerName -f $fileTemplate
[32minfo[39m:    Executing command [1mgroup deployment create[22m
[32minfo[39m:    Supply values for the following parameters
```

EDIT: Link to image showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaRkg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I believe your understanding is not complete. If you see at the last line it says `Supply values for the following parameters`

You need to pass the values for VM name, the admin user name and password, and the Id of the NIC you created previously. My be you should re-read the documentation.  Here is the screenshot for your reference from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/#deploy-a-new-vm-from-the-captured-image -

[image]

Comment: Thats the thing, that prompt never comes up. So if I submit: "azure group deployment create $rgName $computerName -f $fileTemplate", I see the two info lines pop up, but the prompts for vmName, adminUserName, adminPassword and networkInterfaceId never appear, it just hangs with "Supply values for the following parameters" as the last line shown.  It also won't let me provide input.  [Link To Photo](http://imgur.com/a/Fgh8K)

Comment: let me try reproducing this error. I will get back to you shortly.

Comment: May I know why are you using: `azure network vnet subnet create --resource-group $rgName --vnet-name $vnetName --name $subnetName --address-prefix $vnetSubnetAddressPrefix` and not `azure network vnet subnet create $rgName $vnetName $subnetName`  I am sorry but CLI is new to me

Comment: I was just trying to be verbose in case it was the incorrect order for some reason.  I tried it the way you specified and the result is still the same